# Javascript WebSql variables scope

Tags: javascript, web-sql

Why i cant access 'i' variable in transaction?
console.log(data); outputs data successfully.
console.log(data[i]); says undefined..

```
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
            db.transaction(function(tx){
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data[i]);
                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM REGISTERED_EVENTS where EVENT_ID = ?', [data[i].id], function(tx, results){
                   //do something
                }); 
            });
        }
```

Comment: What is the output  of console.log(data)?

Comment: Because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: prints out data array with contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why i cant access 'i' variable in transaction?

You can, but it won't have the value you expect. The transaction callback is called **later**, when the loop has been completed. That callback has an enduring reference to the *variable* `i`, not a copy of its value when the callback was created, and so it sees `i` with the value `data.length`. And so you get `undefined` for `data[i]`.

For this situation, I usually use a builder function so the callback closes over a variable that doesn't change:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    db.transaction(buildHandler(i));
}
function buildHandler(index) {
    return function(tx) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data[index]);
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM REGISTERED_EVENTS where EVENT_ID = ?', [data[index].id], function(tx, results) {
            //do something
        });
    };
}
```

That works because the function that `buildHandler` creates keeps a reference to `index`, and `index` is never changed.

Or, in that *specific* situation, you could get good use out of `Array#forEach`, because it already gives you a variable (well, an argument) that won't change:

```
data.forEach(function(entry, index) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data[index]);
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM REGISTERED_EVENTS where EVENT_ID = ?', [data[index].id], function(tx, results) {
            //do something
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I could'nt try second solution yet, but first one works very well. thanks.